# Dynamic ZK Chart Type & Model: Unsupported model type Error

Tags: zk

I'm creating a dashboard application which requires me to allow user to change the chart type to any other available chart type and reload the org.zkoss.chart.Charts .

```
Charts charts = (Charts) dashboardBuilderCanvas.getFellow(chartsId);
```

I can get the Charts, but when I want to change the type or the model from Column chart to Pie Chart:

```
charts.setType(Charts.PIE);
```

I get the following error:
Unsupported model type [org.zkoss.chart.model.DefaultCategoryModel@5665ad96] on that line.

I tried to do this:

```
PieModel model = new
DefaultPieModel();
charts.setModel(model);
charts.setType(Charts.PIE);
```

But I get the same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported model type [org.zkoss.chart.model.DefaultCategoryModel@5e92429a]
    at org.zkoss.chart.impl.PiePlotImpl.drawPlot(PiePlotImpl.java:33)
    at org.zkoss.chart.Charts.doSmartDraw(Charts.java:2197)
    at org.zkoss.chart.Charts.smartDrawChart(Charts.java:1702)
    at org.zkoss.chart.Charts.setType(Charts.java:662)
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setType` before `setModel`

```
PieModel model = new DefaultPieModel();
charts.setType(Charts.PIE);
charts.setModel(model);
```